# Qual evento/ação usar para mandar excluir um objeto, pelo Event sheet, na Construct 2?

Tags: construct-2

O objeto está no Layer Game, como faço para mandar excluí-lo, no Event Sheet do Layer Game, quando o jogo começar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código acima quando o layout for carregado, o objeto em questão será excluído.

Comment: Obrigado, Dêividy!